# How to generate mouse events for minimized Java window?

Tags: java, mouseevent

I want to generate mouse click events for a Java application. I am aware that there is `java.awt.Robot`, which would allow me to do this. However, I would like that the generated mouse events do not actually affect the "cursor". That is, I would like to be able to minimize the window of the Java program and do other things with the mouse cursor, while mouse events are still generated for that program. How could I do that?

Edit: Furthermore, I cannot be assumed that there is a number of buttons that I need to interact with. Rather I'd like to generate mouse click events as if I had clicked at a certain position within the window.

Comment: I think it is difficult to do this natively, as a window stops receiving a 'heartbeat tick' from most systems if it is not visible (either mininized, or hidden behind other windows) or in some cases even when not focused. So the only option I can think of is some custom event sytem who is not bound to native functionality (like querying absolute element and mouse positions) as those are likely to break when a window is minimized. What are you trying to achieve though? Maybe there is a better approuch than click-event mocking?

Comment: @n247s Could you be more specific what you mean by 'custom event system' please? The Java application is a client with whom I want to interact to gather data to train a machine learning model.

Comment: So you are not programming the client? What I meant by a 'custom event system' is a pure-java implementation (not bound to native functions). But if you have no control over the source-code of the client, than that is not an option anymore, or you have to modify/replace sourcecodes of the client.